# python 3D plot doesn't show anything

Tags: python

The following python code was in a reader from my university for a python course. It should plot a 3D figure but when I try to run the program it doesn't show anything.

```
from numpy import exp,arange,meshgrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D

def z_func(x,y):
    return (1-(x**2+y**3))*exp(-(x**2+y**2)/2)

x = arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1)
y = arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1)
X,Y = meshgrid(x,y)        
Z = z_func(X,Y)     

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.RdBu, 
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show
```

It doesn't give an error or anything.

Comment: use plt.show() 
show is a python function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.show` is a function.  You need to call it: `plt.show()`.